# Excel 2010 return characters in strings in space-delimited files

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

Working with this:

```
A B "C
D"
E F "G
H
```

Excel 2007 opens correctly:

```
col1    col2    col3
A       B       C
                D
--------------------
E       F       G
                H
```

Excel 2010 opens like this:

```
colA    colB    colC
A       B       C
--------------------
D"
--------------------
E       F       G
H"
```

I have " selected as the text qualifier. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241220/generating-csv-file-for-excel-how-to-have-a-newline-inside-a-value Bonus: they may have your solution!

Comment: Thank you. The most important thing I got from all of that: Don't open files with the "wizard."

Comment: What is the etiquette in a situation like this? Edit the thread to request a deletion?

Comment: @Shay Hmm, as long as you still have the problem and searching for another solution, I wouldn't ask for a deletion. Give it some time and maybe another clever guy will come around.